# Class with gridded data: Where to put "read_from_file" method?

Tags: python, class, methods, static-methods

I want to create a class in Python which is called something like "MeteoGrid". It should be able to read data from a netCDF file.

Where should I put the reading function now?
If I put it inside the class and make it a method, it could also be a @staticmethod (taking just the filepath as argument) and is thus a bit "bad practice" in that place if I got that correctly. Should I put it in the **init**(), completely outside the class in the same module or even somewhere else?

I am new to that kind of stuff and maybe a bit lost...thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Does your class REQUIRE having a file to be read from? If yes: The constructor __init__() is a good place.

Comment: Yes, the aim in my case is to build an interface to some provided data which shall be preprocessed. If you want and this is the "final solution" in this case, you can also make it an answer then ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments:

If you REQUIRE having a file for the class to be used the constructor is the best place.

Here is a simple example:

```
class MeteoGrid(object):
    def __init__(self, netcdf_filename):
        # read the data
        with open(netcdf_filename, 'r') as f:
            self.file_content = f.read()

o = MeteoGrid('filename.txt')
```